# How to filter a R dataframe, count the number of filtered rows, and store this count in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working with the two dataframes shown below.

df1 is a dataframe that contains data for individual online business reviews and the date that it was created. I also created features to identify the review as a good review or a bad review based on the review's star rating.

df2 is a dataframe that contains all of the individual visits or 'check ins' at each business and the date it occurred. business_id is the common feature between the two dataframes.

**df1:**

```
 review_id            business_id stars       date BadReview GoodReview  startdate    enddate
1: F2L5ZUhXGQV3eoXker3VhA ---kPU91CF4Lq2-WlRu9Lw     4 2020-06-04         0          1 2020-03-06 2020-09-02
2: rljdEt4_jgsqOgG-7myu-g ---kPU91CF4Lq2-WlRu9Lw     5 2020-03-18         0          1 2019-12-19 2020-06-16
3: fe-yp1-cpfsbL6BUuimP9Q --_9CAxgfXZmoFdNIRrhHA     3 2013-01-07         1          0 2012-10-09 2013-04-07
4: hCjfr9owNP4NfiDtXjgcQg --_9CAxgfXZmoFdNIRrhHA     4 2014-04-29         0          1 2014-01-29 2014-07-28
5: CvdQ_FAJlx8pXdau6p_TlA --_9CAxgfXZmoFdNIRrhHA     4 2010-07-13         0          1 2010-04-14 2010-10-11
6: EVfN8-qleIyBVbmLdV3tVg --_9CAxgfXZmoFdNIRrhHA     5 2013-02-14         0          1 2012-11-16 2013-05-15
   checkincount_before checkincount_after checkin_percentchange
1:              171189             169367             -1.064321
2:              171189             169367             -1.064321
3:              171189             169367             -1.064321
4:              171189             169367             -1.064321
5:              171189             169367             -1.064321
6:              171189             169367             -1.064321
```

**df2:**

```
  business_id              date      
  <chr>                    <date>    
1 --MbOh2O1pATkXa7xbU6LA   2013-04-21
2 --MbOh2O1pATkXa7xbU6LA_1 2013-05-02
3 --MbOh2O1pATkXa7xbU6LA_2 2013-05-04
4 --MbOh2O1pATkXa7xbU6LA_3 2013-05-18
5 --MbOh2O1pATkXa7xbU6LA_4 2013-05-20
6 --MbOh2O1pATkXa7xbU6LA_5 2013-05-22
```

I'm trying to calculate the 90 day moving average of business check ins before and after each review and then calculate the percent change for each review in df1 to determine the average percent change in business check-ins when a good review or bad review is made.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#convert to y-m-d date format
checkins$date <- as.Date(checkins$date)
influencer_reviews$date <- as.Date(influencer_reviews$date, format='%Y-%m-%d',tz= "UTC")

#create column for dates of 90 days before and after review date
influencer_reviews$startdate <- influencer_reviews$date - days(90)
influencer_reviews$enddate <- influencer_reviews$date + days(90)

#create checkin count columns
influencer_reviews$checkincount_after <- 0
influencer_reviews$checkincount_before <- 0

#count number of check ins 90 days before and after each influencer review
for (i in influencer_reviews$checkincount_before) {
  sum(influencer_reviews$business_id %in% checkins$business_id
  & checkins$date > influencer_reviews$startdate
  & checkins$date < influencer_reviews$date)
}

for (i in influencer_reviews$checkincount_after) {
  sum(influencer_reviews$business_id %in% checkins$business_id 
  & checkins$date > influencer_reviews$date 
  & checkins$date < influencer_reviews$endate)
}

#in influencer_reviews, create new column 'checkin_percentchange' that executes the function = (checkincount_after-checkincount_before/checkincountbefore)*100
influencer_reviews$checkin_percentchange <- with(influencer_reviews, ((checkincount_after-checkincount_before)/(checkincount_before))*100)

#calculate mean of checkin_percentchange grouped by positive review and negative review
mean(influencer_reviews[influencer_reviews$GoodReview == '1', 'checkin_percentchange'])
mean(influencer_reviews[influencer_reviews$BadReview == '1', 'checkin_percentchange'])
```

I tried running these for loops to store and count the number of filtered rows but it just ran forever with no results. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

I tried another a similar method without using a for loop and received this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `>.default`(checkins$date, influencer_reviews$startdate) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In influencer_reviews$business_id %in% checkins$business_id & checkins$date >  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In `<.default`(checkins$date, influencer_reviews$date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and example it isn't very clear, although it looks like you are trying to add a date (days+90) on an integer (startdate). Have you tried either converting startdate/enddate to a date or using +/- 90 rather than days(90)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).